# How to achieve accessibility in react-native-render-html in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

When I test accessibility , it does not read the html rendered content.

```
<Text accessible={true}>
          <RenderHtml source={source} renderersProps={renderersProps} />
        </Text>
```

Comment: how you test your RN application with accessiblity?

Comment: <Text accessible={true}> content </Text>

will only work if the content is not through the HTML but here my content is html as I am using  react-native-render-html library, is there way through which I can add accessibility if using this library to display rendered html content ?

Comment: I test by settings>accessibility>Spoken content

Comment: Press the Home button on the iOS device (round button located on the bottom middle of the screen)
 >> Tap Settings.
>> Tap General.
>> Tap Accessibility.
>> Tap VoiceOver.
>> Hold the VoiceOver switch and swipe to the right to turn it on.
>> Hold the Speak Hints switch and swipe to the right to turn it on.

Comment: are you trying using "iframe " inside of RN application?